# SQL (in Progress Database) - Date - Error 7481 - Inconsistent Types

Tags: sql, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

Using SQL on a Progress Database (SQL92)

Using a piece of software (designed for Pervasive) that allows writing of reports etc, which can be emailed to users

I've been receiving the following error with my SQL:

> SQL Debug: [DataDirect][ODBC PROGRESS Driver][PROGRESS]Inconsistent Types (7481)

The following code works perfectly:

```
Select * FROM pub."stockmaster"
Where ("sm-sold" = 0 OR ("sm-sold" = 1 AND "sm-selldate" >= '2017-06-01'))
```

The problem (error) comes when I use the software's built-in 'variables', such as `@MONTHSTART@` which displays as '01 June 2017'

```
Select * FROM pub."stockmaster"
Where ("sm-sold" = 0 OR ("sm-sold" = 1 AND "sm-selldate" >= @MONTHSTART@))
```

I need to use this 'System Variable' so I don't have to keep changing the SQL date manually every month

The Field `"sm-selldate"` is formatted as type Date in Progress

These system variables work perfectly fine on a Pervasive Database

I've searched couple forums and seen suggestions of `CONVERT(DATETIME,` but no workable solution

Comment: Version of Progress? Always good to include that since behavior might have changed.

Comment: PROGRESS Version 9.1E0422, OpenEdge Release 10.2B08

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, 9.1E is ancient...

Perhaps a combination of CURDATE, TO_CHAR and TO_DATE could do it?

I don't run SQL towards OpenEdge so I cannot really test this.

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(MONTH(CURDATE()) + "/1/" + TO_CHAR(YEAR(CURDATE()))
```

My intention ist that the string within TO_DATE should resolve to something like

```
'6/1/2017'
```

(First of June 2017).

Here's the documentation for the 9.1E SQL-92:

https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1777.9-1e-sql-92-guide-and-reference

Comment: It's taking dates (or rather strings) in the Format of _'YYYY-MM-DD'_, In the link: [documentation.progress.com](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvint/format-specifiers-allowed-with-the-to-char-and-t.html) it shows `MM` instead of `MONTH`

Comment: Changing that wouldn't be too tricky. `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(YEAR(CURDATE()) + "-" + TO_CHAR(MONTH(CURDATE()))`? However: you link to version 11.7 of the documentation. It was released April 2017. Your version (according to your comment) is 9.1 - it was released 2004 and retired 2015 - things might very well have changed.

Comment: This is what eventually worked: `'@YEAR@' + '-' + '@MONTH@' + '-' + '01'` Thanks for all the assistance